# PHP Add Symbol If There Is No Price

Tags: php, magento-1.7

There are two products with different quantities and prices

```
    simple product -1 :         qty      price
                                 2        150
                                 3        145
                                 5        130
                                 10      100


    simple product -2 :         qty      price
                                 2        195
                                 5        175
                                 9        170
```

I want to display the quantity and prices in the following format:

```
qty : 2          3          5       9         10

     $150       $145       $130      -        $100

     $195         -        $175     $170       -
```

Below is the code that displays price and qty

```
/*
$_tResult = [2, 3, 5, 9, 2, 5, 10]
*/


     /*
$_tierPrice value


    array(10) {
      ["price_id"] => string(2) "18"
      ["website_id"] => string(1) "0"
      ["all_groups"] => string(1) "1"
      ["cust_group"] => int(32000)
      ["price"] => string(8) "150.0000"
      ["price_qty"] => float(2)
      ["website_price"] => string(8) "150.0000"
      ["formated_price"] => string(34) "150.00"
      ["savePercent"] => float(4)
      ["formated_price_incl_tax"] => string(34) "150.00"
    }

    array(10) {
      ["price_id"] => string(2) "65"
      ["website_id"] => string(1) "0"
      ["all_groups"] => string(1) "1"
      ["cust_group"] => int(32000)
      ["price"] => string(8) "120.0000"
      ["price_qty"] => float(3)
      ["website_price"] => string(8) "120.0000"
      ["formated_price"] => string(34) "120.00"
      ["savePercent"] => float(23)
      ["formated_price_incl_tax"] => string(34) "120.00"
    }

    array(10) {
      ["price_id"] => string(2) "61"
      ["website_id"] => string(1) "0"
      ["all_groups"] => string(1) "1"
      ["cust_group"] => int(32000)
      ["price"] => string(8) "145.0000"
      ["price_qty"] => float(5)
      ["website_price"] => string(8) "145.0000"
      ["formated_price"] => int(5) "145.00"
      ["savePercent"] => float(7)
      ["formated_price_incl_tax"] => string(34) "145.00"
    }

    array(10) {
      ["price_id"] => string(2) "62"
      ["website_id"] => string(1) "0"
      ["all_groups"] => string(1) "1"
      ["cust_group"] => int(32000)
      ["price"] => string(8) "130.0000"
      ["price_qty"] => float(9)
      ["website_price"] => string(8) "130.0000"
      ["formated_price"] => int(5) "130.00"
      ["savePercent"] => float(17)
      ["formated_price_incl_tax"] => string(34) "130.00"
    }

    array(10) {
      ["price_id"] => string(2) "47"
      ["website_id"] => string(1) "0"
      ["all_groups"] => string(1) "1"
      ["cust_group"] => int(32000)
      ["price"] => string(8) "190.0000"
      ["price_qty"] => float(2)
      ["website_price"] => string(8) "190.0000"
      ["formated_price"] => int(5) "190.00"
      ["savePercent"] => float(5)
      ["formated_price_incl_tax"] => string(34) "190.00"
    }

    array(10) {
      ["price_id"] => string(2) "63"
      ["website_id"] => string(1) "0"
      ["all_groups"] => string(1) "1"
      ["cust_group"] => int(32000)
      ["price"] => string(8) "175.0000"
      ["price_qty"] => float(5)
      ["website_price"] => string(8) "175.0000"
      ["formated_price"] => int(5) "175.00"
      ["savePercent"] => float(13)
      ["formated_price_incl_tax"] => string(34) "175.00"
    }

    array(10) {
      ["price_id"] => string(2) "64"
      ["website_id"] => string(1) "0"
      ["all_groups"] => string(1) "1"
      ["cust_group"] => int(32000)
      ["price"] => string(8) "195.0000"
      ["price_qty"] => float(9)
      ["website_price"] => string(8) "195.0000"
      ["formated_price"] => int(5) "195.00"
      ["savePercent"] => float(3)
      ["formated_price_incl_tax"] => string(34) "195.00"
    }

    array(10) {
      ["price_id"] => string(2) "44"
      ["website_id"] => string(1) "0"
      ["all_groups"] => string(1) "1"
      ["cust_group"] => int(32000)
      ["price"] => string(8) "170.0000"
      ["price_qty"] => float(10)
      ["website_price"] => string(8) "170.0000"
      ["formated_price"] => int(5) "170.00"
      ["savePercent"] => float(15)
      ["formated_price_incl_tax"] => string(34) "170.00"
    }
    */




 <?php $_item->setData('tier_price',null); ?>
          <?php $_tierPrices = $this->getTierPrices($_item); ?>
          <?php //print_r($_tResult); ?>
          <?php foreach ($_tierPrices as $price): ?>
                  <td>
                        <?php if(in_array($price['price_qty'],$_tResult)) :?>
                               <?php echo $price['formated_price']; ?>
                        <?php else: ?>
                               <?php echo "-"; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                   </td>    
           <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Below is the actual output of the code.

```
qty :     2          3          5       9         10 

         $150       $145       $130    $100

         $195       $175       $170
```

How do I add "-" when there is no price value in the array

Comment: What is the value of $_tierPrices?

Comment: Hoe does the `$_tierPrices` array look like?

Comment: Just a remark about your code. Opening and closing PHP is an heavy operation, you should not do that in a loop. I suggest you use a template engine like VTemplate for starters http://vtemplate.sourceforge.net/ Then, when you're familiar with the concept you can start using a more powerful one like smarty http://www.smarty.net/

Comment: You have extra `<?php  ?>` ... and `else:` is a typo?

Comment: use isset -- http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: I've added `$_tierPrice` values

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php $_item->setData('tier_price',null); ?>
          <?php $_tierPrices = $this->getTierPrices($_item); ?>
          <?php //print_r($_tResult); ?>
          <?php foreach ($_tierPrices as $price): ?>
            <td>
               <?= (!empty($price['price'])) ? $price['formated_price']: "-"; ?>
            </td>    
           <?php endforeach; ?>
```

If it does not work:

Replace:

```
<?= (!empty($price['price_qty'])) ? $price['formated_price']: "-"; ?>
with
<?= (!empty($price['formated_price'])) ? $price['formated_price']: "-"; ?>
```

Comment or edit your question. Tell us what is output of:

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r($price); echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: In above code doesn't work. Your code output also look like same output i mentioned above. Thank you.

Comment: Did you read full answer? Tried different condition as mentioned? What is output of `echo "<pre>"; print_r($price); echo "</pre>";`

Comment: I getting five product array output look like below :            Array
(
    [price_id] => 18
    [website_id] => 0
    [all_groups] => 1
    [cust_group] => 32000
    [price] => 150.0000
    [price_qty] => 2
    [website_price] => 150.0000
    [formated_price] => $150.00
    [savePercent] => 4
    [formated_price_incl_tax] => $150.00
)

Comment: I just saw... none of your array that comes has a blank price... Please re-structure your array before putting it in foreach

Answer (score -1):

The main logic error in your code, is that the array elements is not equal to the numbers above.

What you need to do is to create an array with the elements and the `[-]` in the keys you want to show it.